# Use list of lists created from orignal list to get remaining values as a list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list that was used to create a new list of lists (sub_lst1) and I want to use that sub_list1 to filter the remaining values in the list.
And use those remaining values to create a new list of lists (sub_lst2).

I have provided a toy example below of the problem.

I have tried the following:

```
lst = ['f','f','a','g','h','a','b','g','h','a','h','d','a','b']

sub_lst1 = []
sub_lst2 = []

>>> for i, v in enumerate(lst):
...     if "b" in v:
...             sub_lst1.append(lst[i-3:i+1])

>>>print(sub_lst1)
[['g', 'h', 'a', 'b'], ['h', 'd', 'a', 'b']]

>>> for i, v in enumerate(lst):
...     if sub_lst1[0:][0:] not in v:
...             sub_lst2.append(lst[i-2:i+1])
>>> print(sub_lst2)
[[], [], ['f', 'f', 'a'],['f', 'a', 'g'], ['a', 'g', 'h'], ['g', 'h', 'a'], ['a', 'b', 'g'], ['b', 'g', 'h'], ['g', 'h', 'a'], ['h', 'a', 'h'], ['a', 'h', 'd'], ['h', 'd', 'a']]
```

But the desired result would be to have the two sub-lists where one sub-list has the two preceding values to 'a' and 'b' and the second sub-list has the two preceding values of 'a' where 'b' does not follow 'a'. The sub-lists would look as follows:

```
>>> print(sub_lst1)
[['g', 'h', 'a', 'b'], ['h', 'd', 'a', 'b']]

>>> print(sub_lst2)
[['f', 'f', 'a'], ['g', 'h', 'a']]
```

Comment: I think you need to update this condition `if sub_lst1[0:][0:] not in v:`, What exaclty are you trying tot check?

Comment: I am trying to split the original list into two list of lists. The first lists of lists would all end in 'a','b' and the second list of lists would end in 'a'. And if the two lists were combined they would produce the original list, having the same number of characters and same characters as the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend tackling this problem by simply finding where the 'b's are and then slicing up the main list in one go, rather than doing it in two steps.  For example:

```
lst = ['f','f','a','g','h','a','b','g','h','a','h','d','a','b']

sub_lst1 = []
sub_lst2 = []

to_find = 'b'
found_indexes = []

for i, v in enumerate(lst):
    if v == to_find:
        found_indexes.append(i)

last_idx = -1
for idx in found_indexes:
    sub_lst2.append(lst[last_idx+1:idx-3])
    sub_lst1.append(lst[idx-3:idx+1])
    last_idx = idx
if lst[-1] != to_find:  # don't forget to check in case 'b' isn't the last entry
    sub_lst2.append(lst[last_idx+1:])
```

This gets the result you are looking for, assuming that if 'b' isn't the last entry, you would want `sub_lst2` to include the trailing letters.

I'm sure there's a solution with superior speed that involves turning the first `lst` into a single string of characters and then `split()`ing it using 'b', but I don't think speed is your concern and this answer will work for a list with contents of any type, not just single characters.

Comment: Unfortunately when I ran your code it did not yield the desired results. I need it to match the desired results exactly as stated in my question, but I appreciate the effort!

Comment: This definitely results in exactly the output you requested at the bottom of your question, so I would check your python installation.  The edit to your question implies that you know with certainty that your initial list will always follow the pattern xxAxxAB, and I think you are getting caught up in that rather than solving the basic problem (splitting the initial list at known places).

Comment: is right this is the solution; thank you!